# Как в matplotlib построить поверхность по ряду 2D-графиков?

Tags: python, matplotlib, график

Есть 3 массива данных, полученных опытным путем(анализ видео): время, ширина, и интенсивность каждой единицы ширины в момент времени(двумерный массив).
Как с использованием matplotlib можно построить поверхность по этим данным?
Не получается стандартными методами, так как нет функции зависимости f(x,y).

Сейчас у меня при помощи цикла строятся 2д линии в трехмерных координатах, что не удобно для визуальной оценки:
[image: график]

Буду благодарен за помощь в решении проблемы.

Comment: пример: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html вместо Z - ваш массив.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!